# >>A. $X$ banch. >>B.M banach. >>C. $X/M$ banach.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to prove that any two will imply the other:

> > A. $X$ banch.
> >
> > B.M banach.
> >
> > C. $X/M$ banach.

I have proved A+B imply C by taking M closed in X. I am not understanding the other two which is said trivial. I dont understand the triviality.

Comment: I edited your post. I hope my edit was appropriate. Can you please verify?

Comment: It omits the part if $X, X/M$ banach then $M$ so. I think this part canbe said by any closed subspace of a complete space complete. Closeness can not be dropped?

Comment: Statement not clear.  You want to show if $X/M$ is a Banach space then $M$ is closed?  Or you want to show if $X/M$ is a Banach space then $M$ is a linear subspace?  Or what?

Comment: Can you talk about your ideals, your thought and what you know about the definition of closed subspace $M$ of $X$?

Comment: I rolled back because I misunderstood the intent of the question. I think the theorem on page 9 here (http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~lwmarcou/Preprints/PM753.pdf) is of interest but it's not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

let $x_n+M$ be a  cauchy sequence in $X/M$ then $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$ and as $X$ is a Banach Space and hence complete.Thus $x_n$ converges to some $x\in X$.Hence $x_n+M$ converges $x+M \in X/M$